# What are factors that might affect alarm in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

If I set a repeating alarm on my application's first run. Then what are the chances that affects the disabling of alarm. I mean if I do not interfere with the alarm then does there is a chance that the android OS will disable it?

Comment: Doze on Marshmellow may interfere with alarms https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Answer (score 0):

Alarm will not be killed by the OS like a normal service. 
In case of repeating alarms, behavior differs from api 21 (or api 19, dont remember). After API 21, repeating alarms are not 'setexact()' i.e. OS will optimize them and alarms may not go off at the exact time specified.
In case of reboot, OS will not automatically reload the alarms for you. You have to handle the logic in 'RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED ?

Comment: http://androidrocksonmobility.blogspot.de/2012/01/how-to-create-auto-start-android.html